# Mark strings as const inside loop body

Tags: c#, string

I have some code with a loop:

```
while(someVariable)
{
    string url = "https://<domain>/<page>/etc..";
    var response = await _httpHandler.GetAsync(url);
    // do something ...
}
```

I want to prevent the compiler from creating a new string object each loop iteration. What would be best - move the url outside of the loop, or simply mark is as const? (and is there a difference btw. the two?)

Comment: The string would be put into the string pool (interned), so no new string objects will be created either way.

Comment: @Sweeper - sounds like a perfectly fine answer to me :)

Comment: If it's not going to change make it a const outside that block... and yes there's a difference, @Sweeper already mentioned what happens.

Comment: also you should consider taking that path / url from a config file, rather than hard coding it. Especially if you use it more often than only this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont worry.!
The compiler dont create a new reference because ***string pool***.

> The string intern pool is a table that contains a single reference to
>   each unique literal string declared or created programmatically in
>   your application. The Common Language Runtime (CLR) uses the intern
>   pool to minimize string storage requirements. As a result, an instance
>   of a literal string with a particular value only exists once in the
>   system.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to move the string outside the loop. I won't be surprised if the compiler does that automatically when optimizations are enabled.

Either way the string will be put on the string pool and [reused anyway](https://brainspeex.wordpress.com/2011/10/30/string-pooling-in-net-c/).